# saving simple checkbox boolean php

Tags: php, mysql

Something basic but I don’t see why it doesn’t work
I want to save the state of a checkbox in a database, type Boolean, if checked 1 else 0 here is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stok"  value="1"
  <?php if(isset($_POST['stok'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>
/>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['stok']) && !empty($_POST['stok']) && $_POST['stok'] === 'on')               
        $stok = 1;  
    else 
        $stok = 0;      

    mysql_query ("update tab set etat_vendu=$stok where id=$big");
?>  

//this is my var $stok=$row['stok'];
```

Comment: `$_POST['stok'] === 'on'` should be `$_POST['stok'] == '1'`, I can't see the value `"on"`

Comment: Hi  @chandresh : No don't work with =='1'

Comment: means what don't work with ==1?

Comment: What is $big, can you post your whole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
if(isset($_POST['stok'])){
    //$stok is checked and value = 1
    $stok = $_POST['stok'];
}
else{
    //$stok is nog checked and value=0
    $stok=0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 

I made the store in database but when I return to modify the product the stock checkbox is not check !!

Answer (score 1):

```php
$stock = $_POST['stok'] ?? 0; // Null coalescing Since PHP7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$_POST['stok'] === 'on'` into `$_POST['stok'] === '1'` in your if.

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement can be shorter, way shorter since you're already passing a value :)

```
if (isset($_POST['stok']))
    $stok = $_POST['stok']; // equals 1 since that's the given value
else
    $stok = 0;
```

Edit: don't forget to check your `UPDATE()` statement:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tab SET etat_vendu='".$stok."' WHERE id='".$big."'");
```

Add data sanitation where necessary.

Comment: What is the problem? Isn't the database updated or is the checkbox not checked while the value in the database is 1?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want now

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT etat_vendu FROM tab WHERE id=".$big);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $stok = $row['etat_vendu'];
    }
```

And your checkbox

```
    <form action='index.php' method='post'>
<?php
    if($stok != 0){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='stok'  value='1' checked='checked'/>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='stok'  value='1'/>";
    }
?>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['stok'])){
                //$stok is checkend and value = 1
                $stok = $_POST['stok'];
            }
            else{
                $stok=0;
            }
?>
```

Comment: No prob, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that

```
if($fetch['proved'] === '1') {
   $p1 = 1;
   $p0 = 0;
} else {
   $p1 = 0;
   $p0 = 1;
}

<select name="proved">
  <option value="<?php echo $p0 ?>"><?php echo $p0 ?></option>
  <option selected value="<?php echo $p1 ?>"><?php echo $p1 ?></option>
</select>
```